# doctrine bidirectional one-to-one relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I know that in symfony2/doctrine, in order to create the bidirectional relationship, we have to tell that into the annotations of the two entities.

What I need though, is to create this bidirectional relationship by modifying only the annotations of only one entity, which means in the other entity annotations there is nothing about the other one.

Is this possible?

Comment: you want an unidirectional one-to-one relation?

Comment: no, I need bidirectional one-to-one relation by modifying only one entity.

Comment: Actually I have an entity which depends on the environment, which means when it's the dev environment my project should see it, but it shouldn't in the prod environment.

Comment: Bi-directional only happens when both entities reference each other. You cant have a bi-directional relationship with just 1 entity. Your problem may be best solved another way however. Why do you have a conditional table based on environment? is there a better way to handle that functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is unidirectional association, the documentation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html?highlight=bidirectional states following rules to achieve bidirectional association:

> The following rules apply to bidirectional associations:
>
> - The inverse side has to use the mappedBy attribute of the OneToOne, OneToMany, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The mappedBy attribute contains the name of the association-field on the owning side.
> - The owning side has to use the inversedBy attribute of the OneToOne, ManyToOne, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The inversedBy attribute contains the name of the association-field on the inverse-side.
> - ManyToOne is always the owning side of a bidirectional association.
> - OneToMany is always the inverse side of a bidirectional association.
> - The owning side of a OneToOne association is the entity with the table containing the foreign key.
> - You can pick the owning side of a many-to-many association yourself.

So I can't be sure if that's possible, but in any case that would probably be breaking the rules, which would possibly cause some errors. Why do you need this kind of association anyway?